# Pyhton Scraped data overwrite itself

Tags: python, excel, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to transfer the information in this code to the excel sheet, but it only transfers the latest data, as far as I understand, it overwrites the information.

How do you think I should go about overcoming this problem? What are your suggestions?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

source = requests.get('url').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_='prd')

for job in jobs:
    product_name = job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['title']
    product_id = job.find('button', class_='prd-favorite btn-add-favorites')['data-product-id']
    product_url = job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['href']
    product_price = job.find('span', class_='prc prc-last').text

df =pd.DataFrame({
    'Col A': [product_name],
    'Col B': [product_id],
    'Col C': [product_url],
    'Col D': [product_price],
})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Every time you run the code, it creates a new `test.xlsx` file which overwrites the previous one. Instead, you should check if an Excel file exists, and in that case open it and append the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your data in a `list` of `dicts` and create your `DataFrame` based on these:

```
...
data = []

for job in jobs:
    data.append({
        'product_name' : job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['title'],
        'product_id' : job.find('button', class_='prd-favorite btn-add-favorites')['data-product-id'],
        'product_url' : job.find('a', class_='prd-link')['href'],
        'product_price' : job.find('span', class_='prc prc-last').text,
    })

pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('test.xlsx')

...
```